# Woocommerce show modal on checkout button click

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, popup

I am implementing a custom payment plugin that extends Woocommerce. When the user clicks on the checkout button, I need to fetch a QR code and display it in a popup.

```
public function process_payment() {
     ...
     try {
        $response = json_decode($this->getQr('url'));
     }
     catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
     }

     $url = $response->url;
     $qr  = $response->qr_code;
}
```

I am getting the response but have no idea how to proceed. Do I need to capture the button click before the `process_payment` function is called?

Answer (score -1):

you can use **woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout** hook. More details http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).